# Xero webhooks with oauth

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to integrate Xero with Business Central and would like to use invoice webhooks to post payments and credits in Business Central.

It is my understanding that Xero webhooks cannot be configured to use oauth but solely does a single call to the URL provided with the key provided, no token or anything?

Or has someone managed to set up a Xero webhook integration with oauth?